# rails 5.1: nested form validation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a parent model called user and 2 nested models called award and certification.  when I go to save a certification the model validation for award tells me that awards is blank, and when I got to save an award I get an error that says the validations for certification is blank.  not sure what's going on.

here my user model

```
  has_many :certifications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :awards, dependent: :destroy


  # allows for nested attributes in the user views.
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :work_histories, :qualifications, :certifications, :courses, :awards,
  :languages, :patents, :publications, allow_destroy: true
```

here my award model

```
    class Award < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :award_name, :award_granted_by, :award_date, :award_description, presence: true  

end
```

and my certification model

```
class Certification < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :certification_name, :certification_authority, :certification_number, :certification_from,
            :certification_to, presence: true

end
```

strong params in users_controller

```
 def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit( :first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :current_job_title, :password, :password_confirmation, 
   work_histories_attributes: [:user_id, :id, :_destroy, :job_title, :company, :description, :city, :state,:start_date, :end_date],
   qualifications_attributes: [:user_id, :id, :_destroy, :education, :university, :university_major, :graduation_year, :currently_enrolled, :location],
   awards_attributes: [:user_id, :id, :_destroy, :award_name, :award_granted_by, :award_date, :award_description],                            
   certifications_attributes: [:user_id, :id, :_destroy, :certification_name, :certification_authority, :certification_number, :certification_from, :certification_to, :cert_never_expires],                           
   courses_attributes: [:user_id, :id, :_destroy, :course_name, :course_number, :course_description],
   languages_attributes: [:user_id, :id, :_destroy, :language, :language_proficiency],
   patents_attributes: [:user_id, :id, :_destroy, :patent_title, :patent_office, :patent_number, :patent_status, :patent_date, :patent_description],
   publications_attributes: [:user_id, :id, :_destroy, :publication_title, :publication_source, :publication_date, :publication_description] )
 end
```

here's a part of the User form.  I've got a button dropdown that has several options, when a user selects an option that particular div will be shown with a modal window.

```
  <!-- one-to-many nested attributes -->  
  <%= form_for(@user) do |form| %>

      <!-- a partial is rendered based on the user dropdown selection -->    
      <div id="award">
        <%= render partial: "awards/new_award_modal", locals: { form: form } %>
      </div>  
      <div id="cert">
        <%= render partial: "certifications/new_certification_modal", locals: { form: form } %>
      </div>                    

    <%= form.submit 'Save', id: "submit-achievement", class: 'btn btn-primary form-control' %>

  </div><!-- modal body -->

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>

  <% end %><!-- form_for -->
```

here is the partial for certifications

```
<div class="new_cert"> 

<%= form.fields_for :certifications, Certification.new do |cert_field| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= cert_field.label :certification_name, 'Certification Title' %>
    <%= cert_field.text_field :certification_name, class: "form-control" %>       
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= cert_field.label :certification_authority %>
    <%= cert_field.text_field :certification_authority, class: "form-control" %>       
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= cert_field.label :certification_number %>
    <%= cert_field.text_field :certification_number, class: "form-control" %>       
  </div>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <div class="field">
        <%= cert_field.label :certification_from, "From" %><br />
        <%= cert_field.date_select :certification_from,{ :order => [:day, :month, :year],
            :start_year => Date.current.year, :end_year => 1960,
            :prompt => {day: 'Day', month: 'Month', year: 'Year'}, :discard_day => true }, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>     
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
      <div class="field">
        <%= cert_field.label :certification_to, "To" %><br />
        <%= cert_field.date_select :certification_to, { :order => [:day, :month, :year], 
            :start_year => Date.current.year + (10), :end_year => 1960,
            :prompt => {day: 'Day', month: 'Month', year: 'Year'}, :discard_day => true }, class: 'form-control'  %>
      </div>        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>  

  <div>
    <%= cert_field.label :cert_never_expires, "This certification does not expire", class: "l" %>
    <%= cert_field.check_box :cert_never_expires, class: 'cb' %>
  </div>
  <br />

<% end %>

</div><!-- ./new_cert -->
```

here's the awards partial

```
<div class="new_award">

  <!-- nested attributes for award modal -->  
  <%= form.fields_for :awards, Award.new do |award_field| %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= award_field.label :award_name, 'Award or Honor Name' %>
        <%= award_field.text_field :award_name, class: "form-control" %>       
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= award_field.label :award_granted_by, "Granted by" %>
        <%= award_field.text_field :award_granted_by, class: "form-control" %>       
      </div>

      <div class="field form-inline">
        <%= award_field.label :award_date, 'Date' %><br />
        <%= award_field.date_select :award_date, { :order => [:day, :month, :year],
            :start_year => Date.current.year, :end_year => 1960,
            :prompt => {day: 'Day', month: 'Month', year: 'Year'}, 
            :discard_day => true }, class: 'form-control ds' %>
      </div>     

      <div class="field">
        <%= award_field.label :award_description, 'Description' %>
        <%= award_field.text_area :award_description, class: "form-control" %>       
      </div>

  <% end %><!-- ./fields_for -->

</div>
```

so both awards and certifications can be saved to the database without any issue when there are no validations.  however, when I just do a simple validation checking for presence of an attribute in the form that's when things get weird.  The award model is saying that the certification form is empty, which it should be because I'm submitting the award form.  And the opposite is also true, when I go to submit a certification the award validation is triggered saying the award form is blank.

Comment: Show your forms

Comment: @MisterCal I just updated with my forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to see the specific error you're getting, but I'd make sure that your form is setting the nested attributes appropriately, and that your `user` controller has nested attributes setup within the strong parameters.

There's documentation in the Rails guides: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: Hi Kara, thanks for responding.  I just updated the question with more info.  Yes I have strong params in the users_controller declared with certifications_attributes[] and awards_attributes[]

Comment: ah, thanks for the updated info! I'm thinking now that it might be based on the fact that you have both form partials as a part of the submission of the larger `form_for`, so it's checking for presence of both attribute fields, even if there have been changes to only one.

Comment: hmm interesting, good suggestion.  I'm going to break it out and make awards and certifications have both the form_for and fields_for instead of trying to use the partials how I'm currently doing.  will post back soon with my results.

Comment: awesome! thanks for the info about not splitting the nested form with partials.  I ditched the partials and switched both nested forms over to use the new form_with and everything is working great.  the form submits and passes validations now.